# Javascript Syntax Highlighter for large strings

Tags: javascript, syntax-highlighting

I'm looking for a high performance syntax highlighter.

I've tried Google prettify, rainbow.js and another one I can't remember. They all struggle with large blocks of HTML code. They eventually all highlight correctly but the browser freezes for a second or two. Or the text isn't highlighted and after a couple of seconds when the page has loaded, it appears all at once.

I had a look at how github uses syntax highlighter and I think he reason it works so well is because groups of text have a single span around it rather than each word, meaning better performance.

Anyone know of a JS syntax highlighters that supports HTML code and can render things really quickly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would it be possible to do the highlighting on the server? Possibly cashing it so you don't have to de it every time. If you post your server-side stack info I can give you links to some libs.

If not can do the syntax highlighting in a worker thread if you want to avoid blocking the UI.

Also, here are a list of 9 other highlighters : http://www.webdesignbooth.com/9-useful-javascript-syntax-highlighting-scripts/

Comment: Fantastic idea! Server side syntax highlighting! I use codeigniter and it has a library for that already! http://caseyamcl.github.com/geshiforci/ - You are a genius thank you for that thought! :)

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in using [Gists](https://gist.github.com/). You can embed them anywhere and the syntax highlighting it uses is extremely speedy.

I'm not meaning to be self-promoting, but for an example of using Gists for Javascript syntax highlighting (I'll be using Gists for HTML as well when I need to), you can check out [my Javascript blog](http://heyjavascript.com/). I don't remember the URLs of any other sites that do this but I have seen them before.

Comment: I don't think Gists will work as I am not doing this manually, I need something automated. Gists won't allow me to print a string to `pre` or `code` block.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's true. Sorry this isn't a solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm aware this is an older question and using the server to highlight large code blocks definitely seems like your best bet.

I just wanted to let you know that I am the author of rainbow.js, and I just pushed out a 2.0 update that moves all syntax highlighting in the browser into a webworker so it should perform better for large code blocks without blocking the main thread/UI.